# SELECT * FROM MULTIPLE TABLE in search QUERY

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php/mysql to perform a search into a furniture website.

I've used a simple search query like this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM produitsoutdoor_new WHERE CONCAT(nom, dimensions, coloris, descriptif, composition, matiere, stock) LIKE '%$keyword%'";
```

But when I try to add some other tables like that:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM produitsoutdoor_new, produitssalon, produitsdecoration WHERE CONCAT(nom, dimensions, coloris, descriptif, composition, matiere, stock) LIKE '%$keyword%'";
```

The result is empty. Any idea of how should I use `JOIN` in this case ?

Comment: use INNER JOIN table ON table2field = table1field

Comment: The `INNER JOIN` will only show values where the ID's exist in all 3 tables. USE `LEFT JOIN` if values may not exist in the joining tables.

Comment: Right approach would be to use an UNION. Besides, OP's actual query (the one he says not working) is doing a Cartesian plan between all tables. And it is not working most probably because of lack of aliases.

Comment: Thank you all. When i read "the schema of all the table is normalised"... i understood.
The tables had not the same columns, so it could not work.
So i normalised and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

There are two likely explanations for "zero rows" being returned by the second query:

1) one of the added tables (`produitssalon` or `produitsdecoration`) contains no rows, or

2) there is an error in the SQL (ambiguous column reference, invalid table reference) which the code is ignorning

---

As to the question you asked:

**Q: how should I use `JOIN` in this case ?**

The comma operator is the old school syntax for a join operation. You could replace the comma with the `JOIN` keyword.

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM produitsoutdoor_new p
     , produitssalon s
     , produitsdecoration d
 WHERE ...
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM produitsoutdoor_new p
  JOIN produitssalon s
  JOIN produitsdecoration d
 WHERE ...
```

Without any conditions to "match" rows, this is going to produce a Cartesian product... every row from `p` matched with every row from `s`, which is then matched to every row in `d`.

Typically we include the matching conditions in an `ON` clause

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM produitsoutdoor_new p
  JOIN produitssalon s
    ON s.p_id = p.id
  JOIN produitsdecoration d
    ON d.p_id = p.id
 WHERE ...
```

With an inner join, if there are no matching rows found in joined table, then no rows will be returned. If we want to return rows even when there is no match, we can use an outer join.  We can specify an outer join by including the keyword `LEFT`:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM produitsoutdoor_new p
  LEFT
  JOIN produitssalon s
    ON s.p_id = p.id
  LEFT
  JOIN produitsdecoration d
    ON d.p_id = p.id
 WHERE ...
```

Whether that's appropriate for this particular case really depends on the actual specification. And having example data and the expected output would help clarify that.

Some suggestions:

Qualify *all* column references with the table name, or a table alias.

Answer (score 0):

if the schema of all the table is normalised it is easy to create the join query on mysql

or

u can join the table in where condition also

if i know ur table it will be easier to create

u can read more on
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp